# RegEx remove content including parentheses from a string

Tags: regex, parentheses

I am trying to figure out how to use regular expressions to remove everything beetween the parentheses from a string. My String is

```
Car (Value: 1.000,00$): Interface
```

The desired output should be as follows:

```
Car: Interface
```

Thanks

Comment: The downvotes are probably because you have showed no attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern:

```
(^\S+)\s\([^)]+\)(.*$)
```

Replacing with:

```
\1\2
```

You can try it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/V1IrRC/1).

Comment: What is the meaning of `[^)]`?

Comment: Its a negated character set, therefore the pattern matches anything except a `)`.

Comment: But why ')' is not allowed then? Thanks!